# Cancel triggering of click event on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<tr class="acord">
 <td colspan="4"><input class="marcatodos" type="checkbox" value="1"/>Clientes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <label>
      <input name="vCliente" class="marcar" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />
      <span class="lbl"> Visualizar Cliente</span>
      </label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <label>
      <input name="aCliente" class="marcar" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="lbl"> Adicionar Cliente</span>
      </label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <label>
      <input name="eCliente" class="marcar" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="lbl"> Editar Cliente</span>
      </label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <label>
      <input name="dCliente" class="marcar" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="lbl"> Excluir Cliente</span>
      </label>
   </td>
</tr>
```

and this jQuery script:

```
$(".acord").click(function() {
   $(this).next("tr").slideToggle(1);
});
```

That's what the HTML generates:

[image]

The jQuery hides the row below the one with a title (class `accord`)

My problem is that when I click on the checkbox, the jQuery triggers it anyway.

How can I make it so the function only runs when I click outside the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to stop the event from bubbling up to the `tr` element

```
$('.marcatodos').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/d987o9kr/) is a fiddle to show the same.

Comment: That was awesome! Worked just fine.

Comment: I have another question: how can i use this checkbox to check all the checkboxes inside the tr?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a particular element triggered the `click` event with the `event`'s `target` property.

```
$(".acord").click(function(e) {            // Make your event handler accept an event parameter
    if (e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {    // Any check against the element
        return;
    } 

    $(this).next("tr").slideToggle(1);
});
```